# Computed display format of date control based on comboBox selection

Tags: xpages

I am trying to change the display format of a date/time control based on a combo box selection. I thought it would be simple to do.

I am using a js if statement with getComponent instead of datasource.getValue as I thought it would grab the value before it is submitted. I receive an error that the component is null.

Can anyone explain why I am getting null here but in a computedField with getcomponent the value shows?

```
if (getComponent('comboBox1').getValue()==0)
    {'both'}

else
    {'date'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the converter is computed during page load, and during this it is not possible to access a component with *getComponent* method. Additionally, it is not possible to recompute the type of the converter this way. Event if you use the *page load/dynamically* trick, the type of the converter will not recomputed.

But you can change the type of the converter in the partial refresh:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="One" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Null" itemValue="0"></xp:selectItem>
       <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="inputText1">
          <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
             var cmp:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("inputText1");
             var converter:com.ibm.xsp.convert.DateTimeConverter = cmp.getConverter();
             var value = getComponent("comboBox1").getValue();

             if( value == 0) {
                 converter.setType("both");
             }else{
                 converter.setType("date");
             }
          }]]>
       </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

In this example, the datefield is *inputText1* and looks like this:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1">
   <xp:this.converter>
      <xp:convertDateTime type="time" />
   </xp:this.converter>
   <xp:dateTimeHelper />
</xp:inputText>
```